# Removing the new line in the last line of a text file using sed

Tags: text, sed

I wanna remove the new line in the last line of my text file using sed. For example the input is like the following:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

And I want to have an output like this without any new lines at the end of the text file:

```
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/\n\+$//' file
```

This will remove a newline(s) at the end of a file provided there are no null characters.

N.B. Normal use of sed i.e. without the `-z` option which slurps the file into memory, will remove any newlines before the sed commands can act on them.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with some test data:

```sh
$ printf "%s\n" {a..e} "" "" | cat -n
     1  a
     2  b
     3  c
     4  d
     5  e
     6
     7
```

I would approach the problem like this: reverse the file, remove blank lines
*at the top*, then re-reverse the file

```sh
$ printf "%s\n" {a..e} "" "" | tac | awk 'NF && !p {p=1}; p' | tac | cat -n
     1  a
     2  b
     3  c
     4  d
     5  e
```

`NF` is the awk variable for "number of fields in this record". `p` is a variable I'm using to indicate when to start printing. The first time that NF is non-zero, we set the `p` variable to a true value. The standalone `p` at the end triggers the default action to print the record.

---

Removing the newline on the last line is a different story.

Given this file:

```sh
$ cat > file
first
second
third
$ od -c file
0000000   f   i   r   s   t  \n   s   e   c   o   n   d  \n   t   h   i
0000020   r   d  \n
0000023
```

We can use perl:

```sh
$ perl -i -0777 -ne 's/\n+$//; print' file

$ od -c file
0000000   f   i   r   s   t  \n   s   e   c   o   n   d  \n   t   h   i
0000020   r   d
0000022
```

or `tr` to translate newlines to some other character, and sed to remove the trailing character

```sh
$ tr '\n' '\034' < file | sed $'s/\034$//' | tr '\034' '\n' | od -c
0000000   f   i   r   s   t  \n   s   e   c   o   n   d  \n   t   h   i
0000020   r   d
0000022
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, this dose not remove the last new line in a text file, we still have a new line in a text file with this approach. I want something to move cursor to the exactly right of the last number or character in the text file, not to the new line after the last number of character. Your approach and other approaches in the web are working when we are printing the results in the terminal, but when we are working with text files and saving the results in the text file this approach won't work.

Comment: Oh, you mean that the last character in the file should not be a newline. Technically, this file will no longer be a "text file" (every line in a "text file" ends with the EOL character(s)).

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
sed '/^$/d' input_file
```

This will remove all empty lines